# Getting sessionId while scheduling job

Tags: session

I am scheduling a job in which i need to pass session Id.
How can i get session id of user at that point.

```
system.schedule('Test process 10 past', '0 10 * * * ?', new TestSchedule(UserInfo.getSessionId()));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that UserInfo.getSessionId() does not work here?  If it does not work, what error are you getting?

Comment: Why do you want the user's session Id in the scheduled job? Won't it be invalid when the job runs?

Comment: @Jagular It is giving error of invalid session Id.

Comment: @Dominic I need to pass the session Id as i have to pass it in authorization header of a web service.

Comment: @pankaj So the batch service makes a callout, and uses the SFDC Session Id to do it? Who is it calling? I'm intrigued about what you're doing.

Comment: @Dominic I need to use getContentAsPdf method, and this i cannot use in batch class, so i am using webservice and creating attachment through it.

Comment: That's interesting. does UserInfo.getSessionId() not work in batch class?

Comment: @Dominic It works but session get expired in 120 minutes. what if my batch runs after that?

Comment: If you can use the code `UserInfo.getSessionId()` inside the batch class itself, then you are using the session of the user that is running the batch. I would think that must be valid all the time the batch is running.